# Настройка dblink Sybase-MySql

Tags: mysql, sybase

Подскажите, может у кого был опыт настройки dblink такой редкой комбинации. Перерыл весь гугл, ответа не нашел.

Есть 2 базы данных, одна Sybase, вторая MySQL. Есть задача, из Sybase выполнять запрос в Mysql для получения данных с последующей обработкой.
Как это сделать проще? Связку Oracle-Mysql настроить удалось, а с sybase решений не нашел :(

Comment: У Sybase разных серверов что блох на собаке... https://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp - у тебя что именно?

Comment:  Adaptive Server Enterprise 12.5.3

Comment: Не, в ASE ничего подобного ODBC linked server не видать..

Comment: @Akina т.е. по сути моя задача не выполнима? Или есть другое решение? Может как-то через Oracle можно вытянуть данные, с учетом того что там dblink настроен.

Comment: Линк через линк? Ну собсно ничто не мешает попробовать, а заработает или нет - это от лукавого.